# ATMEGA 328P Standalone on 3.3v controlling a servo

Tags: servo, atmega328

I'd like to use an ATMEGA 328P on standalone mode powered by a 3.3V supply source to control a servo (which is powered by 4 AA batteries, resulting in 6V). My question is: do I have to convert the PWM signal's peak amplitude to 5V for it to work? Or will the servo work just fine with a 3.3V amplitude signal? My servo's datasheet says its operation voltage ranges from 4.8V to 6V, but I'm not sure if that applies only to its power source or if it has implications on the control signal as well.

Servo's datasheet:
https://www.donkeyhoute.com/UploadFiles/2014916134245511.pdf

Also, since I will be using an 8 MHz external clock, do I have to change anything in my Arduino sketch regarding the PWM signal frequency, or do I just set the board to the 'Lilypad' option when burning the bootloader and keep the sketch the way it is now?

Comment: It's impossible to tell. There's no real data in that datasheet. You'll have to try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I have to convert the PWM signal's peak amplitude to 5V for it to work?

There is insufficient information to determine that.  It may, or it may not. You'll have to try it and see.

> since I will be using an 8 MHz external clock, do I have to change anything in my Arduino sketch regarding the PWM signal frequency

If the board you select is 8MHz then no, you don't need to change anything. The fact you have selected the right frequency for the board means that all the timing calculations the Arduino API does will be correct.